# Documentum Object Type corrupted/ Cannot fetch sys_object

Tags: documentum6.5

I am a bit new to documentum and it seems I have made a mistake.
I had a document with object_type say dm_type1.

I updated the r_object_type with update query to say 'dm_type2'
Now, the problem is 'dm_type2' doesn't exist in system.

Now the document is not accessible;also I aint able to update any properties with DQL.
Any idea how it can be reverted back?

I tried creating a new object type with name dm_type2 wheich is a sub-type of dm_type1 but stillit didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be able to update the r_object_type via DQL, so I have to assume that you use a direct SQL to do that (as you cannot delete an object type from DCTM as long as there are existing objects of that type I also assume that type was not present on the system before the update), so the only way to revert the change back is to update again the r_object_type via SQL on the database and then restart DCTM to refresh the changes.

In order to change a document type you have to use the alter type DQL statement, as an object type consists of several underlying tables that need to be updated in order to keep consistency, and DQL takes care of all the consistency checks that need to be done prior to this change

Comment: Just for the record, changing of type for an object is done by the change type DQL - not by SQL. I cannot remember the exact syntax, but there is a DQL for changing an object's (eg. a document) type.

Answer (score 1):

Try clearing the cache. You can do that via API call.
There is AFAIK three caches. It should obviously be the type cache.
Good luck.
Br.